# OutputType<X> is not getting resolved in Webdriver

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have below code:

> TakesScreenshot sc = (TakesScreenshot)driver;  File srcfile =
> sc.getScreenshotAs(OutputType);

Here the Output is not getting resolved to a type.
Can anyone guide as to how to resolve this.

Comment: the purpose of that code is taking a screenshot right ?

Comment: @user9261795 Update the question with the complete error stack trace

Comment: @Asmoun: The purpose of this code it taking screenshot.Here there is no run time stack trace as Output<x> is not getting resolved to a type.

Answer (score 0):

`getScreenshotAs();` takes parameter value of a `OutputType`.

You should mention a OutputType among these available options `FILE`,`BYTES` or `BASE64` as mentioned in [`OutputType<T>`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/OutputType.html) interface

Change your code to:

```
TakesScreenshot sc = (TakesScreenshot)driver; 
File srcfile = sc.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```